# Tensorflow: method to save and restore TensorFlowEstimator()

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

How to save and load this object (`regressor`)?

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
regressor = learn.TensorFlowEstimator()
```

I could not use tensorflow's default Saver() to save it.

How to do incremental learning with this model? I am confused about `continue_training` parameter in its constructor. It says you can call fit again and again with new data. And at the same time it provides `partial_fit()`. Please help me understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [TF tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow#saving--restoring-models), the following should work:

for saving:

```
regressor.save('/tmp/tf_examples/my_model_1/')
```

for restoring:

```
new_regressor = TensorFlowEstimator.restore('/tmp/tf_examples/my_model_2')
```

---

For incremental training: Please refer the following details. They've given pretty much good explanation.

[continue_training](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.learn.TensorFlowEstimator.md#tfcontriblearntensorflowestimator__init__model_fn-n_classes-batch_size32-steps200-optimizeradagrad-learning_rate01-clip_gradients50-class_weightnone-continue_trainingfalse-confignone-verbose1-tensorflowestimatorinit) - set this to `True`, the model initialized once and it will be continually trained on every call of fit.

[partial_fit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.learn.TensorFlowEstimator.md#tfcontriblearntensorflowestimatorpartial_fitx-y-tensorflowestimatorpartial_fit) - Incremental fit on a batch of samples

Comment: thanks , it solved my problem. Can you please help me with my second doubt as well (statement updated).